# Delimiting string in R

Tags: r, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have this challenge:

I want to be able to extract one portion of a string in the following manner:

1. The string may or may not have a dot or may have plenty of them
2. I want to extract the string part that is before the first dot, if there is no dot then I want the whole string
3. I want to use a regex to achieve this

```
    test<-c("This_This-This.Not This",
            "This_This-This.not_.this",
            "This_This-This",
            "this",
            "this.Not This")
```

Since I need to use a regex, I have been trying to use this expression:

```
str_match(test,"(^[a-zA-Z].+)[\\.\\b]?")[,2]
```

but what I get is:

```
> str_match(test,"(^[a-zA-Z].+)[\\.\\b]?")[,2]
[1] "This_This-This.Not This" "This_This-This.not_this"
[3] "This_This-This"          "this"                   
[5] "this.Not This"          
>
```

My desired output is:

```
"This_This-This"
"This_This-This"
"This_This-This"
"this"
"this"
```

This is my thought process behind the regex

```
str_match(test,"(^[a-zA-Z].+)[\\.\\b]?")[,2]
```

**(^[a-zA-Z].+)=** this to capture the group before the dot since the string starts always with a letter cpas or lower case, and all other strings after that that's why the .+

**[\.\b]?**=a dot or a world boundary that may or may not be that's why the ?

This is not giving what I want. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My regex is "match anything up to either a dot or the end of the line".

```
library(stringr)
str_match(test, "^(.*?)(\\.|$)")[, 2]
```

Result:

```
[1] "This_This-This" "This_This-This" "This_This-This" "this" "this"
```

Comment: neilfws thank you so much! I have a question I just wrap my head around this: if I use str_match(test, "^(.*?)(\\.|$)")  then it works perfectly but if I use str_match(test, "^(.*?)(\\.|\\.b)")  it return: "" , "", "","","" is not the last code telling R to look for a dot or a word boundary which will happen? and please let me know what would you use the ? after .*, what I get is that .* mean capture everything (.) zero or more times (*) but the ('?) means zero or 1 time like I dont get it, I will be so happy if you could please explain to me thank you in advance from the bottom of my heart

Answer (score 3):

Actually, rather than extracting, a regex replacement should work well here:

```r
test <- c("This_This-This.Not This",
          "This_This-This.not_.this",
          "This_This-This",
          "this",
          "this.Not This")
output <- sub("\\..*", "", test)
output

[1] "This_This-This" "This_This-This" "This_This-This" "this"          
[5] "this
```

Replacement works well here because it no-ops for any input not having any dots, in which case the original string is returned.

Answer (score 0):

A simple extraction is with `str_extract` and a negative characterclass matching anything but a `.`:

```
libraryr(stringr)
str_extract(test, "[^.]+")
[1] "This_This-This" "This_This-This" "This_This-This" "this"           "this"
```

Data:

```
test <- c("This_This-This.Not This",
          "This_This-This.not_.this",
          "This_This-This",
          "this",
          "this.Not This")
```